# C++ Problems with printf and ASCII

Tags: c++, ascii

I'm trying to print out single alphabet characters based on this example

```
char alphabet[27]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = i + 97; 
}
alphabet[26] = 0; 
printf("%s\n", alphabet); 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = i + 65; 
}
printf("%s\n", alphabet);
```

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
char singleAlphabetTest[1];
singleAlphabetTest[0] = 97;

printf("%s\n", singleAlphabetTest);
```

the first code is working fine but my code would print below in console:

> a╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: You did something special in the first bit of code, but not in the 2nd one: can you explain why you did `alphabet[26] = 0;`? Only that, specific statement. Once you explain why you did that, the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out, this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for printing string you should have at least two characters
one is for a character another one is for '\0'

```
char singleAlphabetTest[2];
singleAlphabetTest[0] = 97;
singleAlphabetTest[1] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", singleAlphabetTest);
```

In c %s is to print an array of character ending with '\0'

I want to emphasize the example that you gave

```
char alphabet[27]; 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = i + 97; 
}
alphabet[26] = 0; //important!the string ending with 0 or '\0'
printf("%s\n", alphabet); 
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    alphabet[i] = i + 65; 
}
printf("%s\n", alphabet);
```